# I changed text size to 0 in gnome tweak

Tags: text

I've just changed text size to 0 in Gnome Tweak app. Then all of the texts in the app have gone. So I can't change text size anymore. I don't know what to do :D Is there any way to fix it using Terminal? Using Ubuntu 12.04. Waiting for help.

Comment: I love experimenting. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the settings file and log out and you will be fine.

Removing the dconf binary file:

```
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
```

Restarting xorg:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: Warning: this removes a lot of other settings too. There is probably a way to just set a valid font size again.